# Angular Form: Cannot read property 'cafPlanForm' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular5, ng-bootstrap, angular-forms

In a Angular 5 "aplication", I'm trying to create a custom validation for two different inputs fieds but I cannot access to any of my inputs value, I'm getting that error so I'm not able to create a condition to create my custom validation

That's my typescript file:

```
import { NgbDateParserFormatter } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbDateFRParserFormatter } from '../../../models/ngb-date-fr-parser-formatter';
import { Key } from 'protractor';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-caf-creation-tabs',
  templateUrl: './caf-creation-tabs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./caf-creation-tabs.component.css'],
  providers: [{ provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: NgbDateFRParserFormatter }]
})
export class CafCreationTabsComponent implements OnInit {

  public titleTabs = "Plan";
  model: number;
  model2: String;
  cafPlanForm: FormGroup;
  public errorDate: any = { isError: false, errorMessage: '' };


  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createCafCreationForm();
  }

  createCafCreationForm() {
    this.cafPlanForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      planName: ['', Validators.required],
      planStartDate: ['', Validators.required, this.dateStartValidation],
      planEndDate: ['', Validators.required],
      planComments: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  limitationDate() {
    let parts = this.cafPlanForm.controls['planStartDate'].value

    let startDate = new Date();
    let endDate = new Date(this.cafPlanForm.controls['planEndDate'].value);
    console.log(startDate + "     " + endDate);
    if (startDate > endDate) {
      this.errorDate = {
        isError: true,
        errorMessage: "Error Date"
      }
    }
  }
//: { [key: string]: boolean } | null
  dateStartValidation(control: FormControl) {
    if(control.value != undefined){
      console.log(control.value);
      console.log(this.cafPlanForm.get('planEndDate'));      
    }
  }



}
```

This is my html component:

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">

    <ngb-tabset>

      <ngb-tab title="{{ titleTabs }}">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center mt-5 px-3">



            <form class="col-12" [formGroup]="cafPlanForm">
              <div class="form-group row form-space">
                <label for="planName" class="col-2 col-form-label">Plan Name:</label>
                <div class="col-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0 border-gray-lighten-2" id="planName" formControlName="planName">
                  <div class="mt-1 ml-1" *ngIf="cafPlanForm.controls['planName'].invalid && cafPlanForm.controls['planName'].touched">
                    <small class="text text-danger">Error</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="d-flex flex-wrap m">

                <div class="form-group flex-row form-space col-6 px-0">
                  <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                    <div class="col-4 px-0">
                      <label for="planStartDate" class="col-form-label">Plan Start Date:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group col-5 px-0 ml-1">
                      <div class="d-flex flex-row col-12 px-0">
                        <input class="form-control rounded-0 border-gray-lighten-2" name="planStartDate"  ([ngModel])="model" ngbDatepicker
                          #d="ngbDatepicker" formControlName="planStartDate">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                          <button class="btn btn-outline-dark rounded-0 border-gray-lighten-1 date-picker-caf" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
                            <i class="material-icons " style="cursor: pointer;">date_range</i>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="ml-2 mt-1 position-relative">
                        <small class="text text-danger" *ngIf="cafPlanForm.controls['planStartDate'].invalid && cafPlanForm.controls['planStartDate'].touched"> Error</small>
                        <small class="text text-danger" *ngIf="errorDate.isError == true">Error Date</small>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group flex-row form-space col-6">
                  <div class="d-flex flex row justify-content-end">
                    <div class="col-4">
                      <label for="planStartDate" class="col-form-label ml-auto">Plan End Date:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group col-5 px-0">
                      <div class="d-flex flex-row col-12 px-0">
                        <input class="form-control rounded-0 border-gray-lighten-2" name="planEndDate" id="planEndDate" [(ngModel)]="model2" ngbDatepicker
                          #d2="ngbDatepicker" formControlName="planEndDate">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                          <button class="btn btn-outline-dark rounded-0 border-gray-lighten-1 date-picker-caf" (click)="d2.toggle()" type="button">
                            <i class="material-icons " style="cursor: pointer;">date_range</i>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="ml-2 mt-1 ">
                        <small class="text text-danger" *ngIf="cafPlanForm.controls['planEndDate'].invalid && cafPlanForm.controls['planEndDate'].touched">Error</small>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>


              <div class="form-group row form-space">
                <label for="planComments" class="col-2">Plan Comments:</label>
                <div class="col-10">
                  <textarea type="text" class="form-control rounded-0 border-gray-lighten-2" id="planComments" rows="5" formControlName="planComments"></textarea>
                  <div class="mt-1 ml-1" *ngIf="cafPlanForm.controls['planComments'].invalid && cafPlanForm.controls['planComments'].touched">
                    <small class="text text-danger">Error</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>

      <ngb-tab title="Plan PDF">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center mt-5">
            <form class="col-12">
              <div class="form-group row form-space">
                <label for="planVersionStartDate" class="col-2 col-form-label">Plan Version Start Date:</label>
                <div class="input-group col-3">
                  <input class="form-control rounded-0 border-gray-lighten-2" name="planVersionStartDate" id="planVersionStartDate" [(ngModel)]="model"
                    ngbDatepicker #planVersionStartDate="ngbDatepicker">
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark rounded-0 border-gray-lighten-1 date-picker-caf" (click)="planVersionStartDate.toggle()"
                      type="button">
                      <i class="material-icons " style="cursor: pointer;">date_range</i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <label for="planEndDate" class="col-2 col-form-label ml-auto">Plan Version End Date:</label>
                <div class="input-group col-3">
                  <input class="form-control rounded-0 border-gray-lighten-2" name="planStartDate" id="planStartDate" [(ngModel)]="model2"
                    ngbDatepicker #d2="ngbDatepicker">
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark rounded-0 border-gray-lighten-1 date-picker-caf" (click)="d2.toggle()" type="button">

                      <i class="material-icons " style="cursor: pointer;">date_range</i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr>
              <div class="form-group row form-space mt-4">
                <label for="planPDF" class="col-2 col-form-label">Plan PDF:</label>
                <div class="col-3">
                  <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input rounded-0 border-gray-lighten-2" id="inputGroupFile01" hidden>
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01"></label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row form-space">
                <label for="planPDFComments" class="col-2 col-form-label">Comments:</label>
                <div class="col-10">
                  <textarea type="text" class="form-control rounded-0 border-gray-lighten-2" id="planComments" rows="5"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>

      <ngb-tab title="Job Codes">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center mt-5">

          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>

    </ngb-tabset>

    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

How could I slve this issue? 
I've been stuck many hours

Comment: Try calling `this.createCafCreationForm();` in the constructor instead of in ngOnInit().

Comment: It doesn't wokr but thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is, is that you need to call it in the contructor. Here is an example I found online on how to use FormBuilder. https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-form-builder-and-validation-management

I've never used FormBuilder before though, here is how I typically do Angular Forms.

Typescript:

```
export class UserInfoComponent {
    firstName: FormControl;
    lastName: FormControl
    myFormGroup: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        firstName = new FormControl();
        lastName = new FormControl();

        this.myFormGroup = new FormGroup ({
        firstName: this.firstName,
        lastName: this.lastName
        })
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
    <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
</form>
```

You can access any of your form elements with 'firstName.value'
Here is the documentation for it: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

There is also valueChanges for both FormControl and FormGroup which you can subscribe to.

If the problem is that your custom validator isn't working at all let me know and I can expand on my answer to include that.